# Calling a method inside of init function python

Tags: python-2.7, init

I'm having an issue with this code:

```
import math

class Money(object):

    def __init__(self, salary):
        self.salary = salary
        sal(self.salary)

    def sal(self, x):
        y = ( x - ( ( (x * 0.22) + 6534) ) -  (1900.9408 + ( (x - 37568)*.077) ) )
        print '-----------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'monthly income before tax will be: ${0:.2f}' .format(x/12)
        print 'bi-weekly income before tax will be: ${0:.2f}' .format(x/24)
        print 'Hourly after tax: ${0:.2f}' .format(x/24/70)
        print '-----------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'Income after tax will be: ${0:.2f}' .format(y)
        print 'Monthly after tax: ${0:.2f}' .format((y/12))
        print 'bi-weekly after tax:  ${0:.2f}' .format((y/24))
        print 'Hourly after tax: ${0:.2f}' .format(y/24/70)


        answer = raw_input('Do you want to do this again?\nType [Y] or [N]: ')
        if( answer == 'Y'):
            sal(x)
        else:
            print 'Thank you!'
            return


def main():

    x = input('Enter your taxable income: ')
    salaryLister = Money(x)

main()
```

The traceback shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "taxableincome.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "taxableincome.py", line 33, in main
    salaryLister = Money(x)
  File "taxableincome.py", line 7, in __init__
    sal(self.salary)
NameError: global name 'sal' is not defined
```

What does:
global name 'sal' is not defined mean?

Feel free to make comments about my design as well. I'd love to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `self.sal`, this is how you call instance methods of classes in python

How this works in python is, If you look at the method signature you have

```
def sal(self, salary)
```

basically, it needs the class reference as the first variable. And in python when you do `self.sal` it translates to

```
Money.sal(self, salary)
```

You can also call the method like this, but the recommended way is

```
self.sal(salary)
```

As per comments on your code, There definitely aren't any clear red flags. Though the last `return` statement in the sal function is not required. Its not a problem having it there, just something that caught my eye.

Also since you asked, I'd like to point this out. Please try to keep to a coding standard. let it be your own or someone else's. The important thing is consistency. But PEP-8 is generally the accepted style for python. You even have plugins for your editor which help you stick to it. You might want to read the style guide linked [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).